# How can I access access header values of a REST GET message with Spring/Kotlin

Tags: spring, rest, http, kotlin, get

For restful communication I am building a Server-Backend with Kotlin using Spring.

I have the following code for a GET request. For now I am pretty new to Kotlin and also to the Spring library. Can somebody explain me, how I can access the values in the header of the GET message?

I guess @RequestHeader is somehow used for this? Will it be the same for other message types as POST, UPDATE etc?

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
class UserRestController(val userManager: UserManager) {

    @GetMapping("specific_user_lean")
    fun getSpecificUserLean(@RequestParam(value ="id") id: String) = run {
        userManager.loadUserByID(id) // returns null or a User object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use for it @RequestHeader as stated in spring documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestheader

There is also example for Kotlin:

```
@GetMapping("/demo")
fun handle(
    @RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") encoding: String, 
    @RequestHeader("Keep-Alive") keepAlive: Long) { 
    //...
}
```

This example accepts "Accept-Encoding" and "Keep-Alive" headers.

If you want to accept all headers, than you should collect them in Map.

```
@GetMapping("/demo")
fun handle(
    @RequestHeader allHeaders: Map<String, String>) { 
    //...
}
```

Yes, @RequestHeader annotation works for POST, PUT and other methods.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Your hint was so valuable for me. For some reason I didnt find this docs.spring.io page